# Mapbox GL JS + Custom 3D Layer (three.js): flicker and disappears

Tags: three.js, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to add multiple 3D models to a custom mapbox layer. I'm testing with a single 3d model first, similar to this example (https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-3d-model/) but with a different gltf file.

The problem is that the model flickers then disappears and i'm unsure how to begin to troubleshoot this. Perhaps, there needs to be customized settings for each model?

Codepen Link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-proskuriakova-uqwuk?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Your codesandbox returns an error loading the model

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

    at GLTFLoader.parse (https://uqwuk.csb.app/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js:114:23)

    at Object.eval [as onLoad] (https://uqwuk.csb.app/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js:61:17)

    at XMLHttpRequest.eval (https://uqwuk.csb.app/node_modules/three/build/three.module.js:1:876492)
​
```

It seems your model is not well formed as GLTF, could you share the model on a folder or url to download.

Comment: @jscastro, yeah i can't explain why there is a syntax error when im copying and pasting the json describing the gltf object straight off here: https://github.com/jscastro76/threebox/blob/master/examples/models/radar/34M_17.gltf. I think the file is being recognized as a .txt file instead of .gltf

Comment: @jscastro Anyway, thanks for updating threebox. I abandoned trying to loading multiple 3d objects with a pure three.js solution and instead used threebox (: